# Call for help, there's something amiss!

Tags: riddle

> Eleven gents in academic training environment
>   Exist as groups under elevated superiors
>   And by organizing ranks and, together, inspiring very excitable little yippers
>   Enable convening those
>   Intelligent elegant shepherds
>   Ambling ‘round, lacking encircling scruff straps, looking youthful

What on earth is going on here?

Comment: This is the first riddle I've posted. Feedback is encouraged, and if more experienced users feel that there are other tags that apply, please feel free to add them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks as if this is less of a puzzle and more of a

> Coll for help,

because

> Each line provides a description of something, and by adding Coll- before the first letter of each word it will spell it out.
>
>  - Collegiate
>  - Colleagues
>  - Collaboratively
>  - Collect
>  - Collies
>  - Collarlessly

Comment: Feedback: it is fun and not too difficult.

Comment: I guess you'll be collecting a green checkmark soon.

Comment: Nicely observed. I like how you answered with a pun.

Comment: Bingo. Would you mind explaining your thought process? Which line was the key to recognizing what was going on? Also - I'm glad to see you got the pun in the title! You used it in essential the same way I was planning to, if a hint became necessary.

Comment: As an idiot relative to this stack exchange, I gotta say-- I was barking up the wrong tree. I thought it had to do with dog training or obedience school. I was trying to fit the title into Call of the Wild.

Comment: One more thing to point out: the answer is a complete, gramatically-correct (more or less) sentence where rot13(nyy jbeqf ortva jvgu gur fnzr sbhe yrggre cersvk) which describes the same situation as the clue